# Create "fake" new type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have many functions which accept an ID as an argument (currently of type `string`).

I would like to replace this with the type `ID` which is still just a string, but would allow me to take advantage of static checking to make sure I am passing arguments correctly.

Comment: `type ID = string;`

Comment: here is one example https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/types.ts#L52

Comment: @4castle With that method, passing any string to the function leads to it compiling without error, while I would hope that it would raise an error.

Comment: @artem That appears to work. I assume I just leave the brand field undefined and force a type conversion with `as`?

Comment: @artem Unforunately the new type is no longer usable as an index to other objects.

Comment: please be more specific with requirements in your question. Yes that type is not compatible with string literal types, but using it for accessing types indexed by strings  [appears to work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Path%20%3D%20string%20%26%20%7B%20__pathBrand%3A%20any%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20r%20%3D%20'a'%20as%20Path%3B%0D%0Aconst%20o%3A%20%7B%20%5Bn%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0Ao%5Br%5D%20%3D%20'2'%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Hmm I had a problem in my larger program, but yes your sample and a small example I wrote both seem to work, I'll see if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Also since you did answer my original question regardless, feel free to add your original comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to make ID equivalent to an string.

In any situation like that you either want to use a string - There is no way to tell from a typescript perspective they are different since you are just reusing the same exact type. Doing something like:

```
type ID = string
```

Will not help out since a string will still be valid. You cannot use "typeof" effective even then because:

```
type ID = string;

class WorkWithIDs {
    public alertID(data: ID) {
        alert(typeof (data));
    }
} 

let testWorkWithIDs = new WorkWithIDs();
let actualID: ID;
testWorkWithIDs.alertID("dsfsdf");
testWorkWithIDs.alertID(actualID);
```

Alerts:
 - string
 - undefined

In your own words, ID is a string, for now. Why not use a regular class called "ID", which you can extend all you want and already works for type checking?

So, as far as I know there is no current way to do what you want with the tools Typescript provide, that is make a type of another type that does enforce that base type cannot be used as an input.